# problem in converting latin1 to utf8 for a table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in converting all my tables' charset latin1 to utf8. Maximum tables are converted but some tables showed that

> ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 255
>   bytes

Here in my table I am  using primary key with an 3 elements. The elements length is 128,64,128 respectively. Can anybody solve this? Advanced thank you.

i federated this table.from another database.the base table engine is MYISAM.

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL`, `UTF8` characters can take up to `3` bytes.

Hence, the max length of your PK can be `(128 + 64 + 128) * 3 = 960` bytes which exceeds `255` bytes allowed by the engine.

BTW, what storage engine are you using? `InnoDB` allows `767` bytes and `MyISAM` allows `1000` bytes.